# Selecting item in NavigationView overflow list programatically

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

When I try to programmatically select an item that is in the "overflow list" of a `NavigationView`, I get the following error:

> The parameter is incorrect.
>
> container'

An example is the following picture, where I try to select Menu Item 3 programatically:

---

[image: NavigationView overflow]

`var nextItem = dataSource.indexOf(menuItem3);
 NavView.SelectedItem = nextItem;`

---

It works fine when selecting an item that is not overflowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The parameter is incorrect. container'

For explain this behavior, we need check `NavigationView` style in the **Generic.xaml** file.

```
<Button 
    x:Name="TopNavOverflowButton"
    Grid.Column="4"

    Content="More"
    Style="{StaticResource NavigationViewOverflowButtonStyleWhenPaneOnTop}"
    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.OverflowButtonVisibility}">

    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,8" />
                    <!-- Set negative top margin to make the flyout align exactly with the button -->
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-4,0,0" />
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <NavigationViewList x:Name="TopNavMenuItemsOverflowHost" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" SingleSelectionFollowsFocus="False" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
                <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection />
                </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
            </NavigationViewList>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

As you can see, the *More items* stored in the **TopNavMenuItemsOverflowHost** `NavigationViewList`. and it's container is [`Flyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout). The Flyout is lazy load control. If it does not popup, it's content will not be loaded. This is why the container is missing.

I think it is not reasonable that focus inconclusive item in the `TopNavMenuItemsOverflowHost`.  if you want select item correctly, please make sure enough window width that could make all items displayed in the `NavigationView`.